# Need help to compile a program for GuruPlug (ARM based)

Tags: c, linux, opencv

I'm newbie with Linux OS, and I'm building a C program for transmit video through Power Line. 
I use Opencv 2.4.9 to compile my program in Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked. But when I tried to Compile this program using Opencv and copy the client file ( I don't know exactly the file type, but it can be run by using command: "./client") to my GuruPlug, i got a error

" Can not execute binary file "

I have tried it with simple program "Hello World" and copy into my GuruPlug and it worked.

My question is: How can I run my Client file on my GuruPlug without any error?

Thanks for read my problem.

P/s: sorry for my English

Comment: Jack, edit your question.  Add the output of the Linux command: ls -l client

Answer (score 0):

Try the Linux command:

```
chmod 744 client
```

Then try running again using command:

```
./client
```